# An error in the checkers code, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Made a small game, the main goal is to remove all the pieces by jumping over the checkers. The first time it is possible to remove the checker, the second time it gives an error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'theRow' of undefined

On line 180. I looked at the line, here it is.

[image]

Code:

```js
Point = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas;
  var context;
  var BB;
  var offsetX;
  var offsetY;
  var dragok = false;
  var startX;
  var startY;
  var oldX, oldY;
  var fieldArray = [
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ];
  var shapes = [];
  var possibleLandings = [];
  var localX, localY;
  var pickedMonster;
  var sx = 0;
  var sy = 0;
  var i1 = 0;

  function draw() {

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.save();

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < fieldArray[i].length; j++) {
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeRect(j * 60, i * 60, 60, 60);
        context.fillRect(j * 60, i * 60, 60, 60);
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
      circle(shapes[i]);
    }

    context.restore();
    if (possibleLandings.length > 0) {
      context.save();
      context.fillStyle = "#4CFF00";
      context.fillRect(oldX, oldY, 20, 20);
      context.restore();
    } else {
      context.save();
      context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
      context.fillRect(oldX, oldY, 20, 20);
      context.restore();
    }
  }

  function circle(c) {

    context.fillStyle = c.fill;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
  }

  function myDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    dragok = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
      var s = shapes[i];
      var dx = s.x - mx;
      var dy = s.y - my;

      if (dx * dx + dy * dy < s.r * s.r) {
        dragok = true;
        s.isDragging = true;

        pickedMonster = {
          x: s.x,
          y: s.y,
          i: i,
          theRow: s.theRow,
          theCol: s.theCol
        };
        oldX = s.x;
        oldY = s.y;
        localX = mx - s.x + (30 / 2);
        localY = my - s.y + (30 / 2);
        checkMonster(s);
        canvas.onmousemove = moveMonster;
        canvas.onmouseup = dropMonster;
      }
    }
    startX = mx;
    startY = my;
  }

  function moveMonster(e) {
    if (dragok) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
      var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
      var dx = mx - startX;
      var dy = my - startY;
      for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        var s = shapes[i];

        if (s.isDragging) {
          s.x += dx;
          s.y += dy;
          pickedMonster.x = e.clientX - localX;
          pickedMonster.y = e.clientY - localY;
        }
      }

      draw();
      startX = mx;
      startY = my;
    }
  }

  function dropMonster(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var legalMove = false;

    var dropX = Math.floor((pickedMonster.x + 30) / 60);
    var dropY = Math.floor((pickedMonster.y + 30) / 60);
    console.log(dropX);

    for (var i = 0; i < possibleLandings.length; i++) {

      if (possibleLandings[i].x == dropY && possibleLandings[i].y == dropX) {

        legalMove = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!legalMove) {

      shapes[pickedMonster.i].x = oldX;
      shapes[pickedMonster.i].y = oldY;
    } else {

      var rowOffset = (dropY - pickedMonster.theRow) / 2;

      var colOffset = (dropX - pickedMonster.theCol) / 2;

      fieldArray[pickedMonster.theRow][pickedMonster.theCol] = 0;
      fieldArray[pickedMonster.theRow + rowOffset][pickedMonster.theCol + colOffset] = 0;
      fieldArray[pickedMonster.theRow + 2 * rowOffset][pickedMonster.theCol + 2 * colOffset] = 1;

      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var currentMonster = shapes[i];
        if (currentMonster.theRow == pickedMonster.theRow + rowOffset &&
          currentMonster.theCol == pickedMonster.theCol + colOffset) {
          shapes.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    dragok = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
      shapes[i].isDragging = false;
    }
    draw();
  }

  function checkMonster(s) {

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var deltaRow = (1 - i) * (i % 2 - 1);

      var deltaCol = (2 - i) * (i % 2);
      if (checkField(s, deltaRow, deltaCol)) {

        possibleLandings.push(new Point(s.theRow + 2 * deltaRow, s.theCol + 2 * deltaCol));
      }
    }
  }

  function checkField(s, rowOffset, colOffset) {


    if (fieldArray[s.theRow + 2 * rowOffset] != undefined &&
      fieldArray[s.theRow + 2 * rowOffset][s.theCol + 2 * colOffset] != undefined) {
      if (fieldArray[s.theRow + rowOffset][s.theCol + colOffset] == 1 &&
        fieldArray[s.theRow + 2 * rowOffset][s.theCol + 2 * colOffset] == 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  function main() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.style.background = "#A0A0A0"
    BB = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(150,190,255)';
    context.globalAlpha = 0.7;
    offsetX = BB.left;
    offsetY = BB.top;
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++) {

      for (var j = 0; j < fieldArray[i].length; j++) {

        if (fieldArray[i][j] == 1) {
          shapes.push({
            x: j * 60 + 30,
            y: i * 60 + 30,
            r: 30,
            theRow: i,
            theCol: j,
            fill: "#444444",
            isDragging: false
          });
        }
      }
    }
    draw();
    canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
  }
  main();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="drawingCanvas" width="500" height="500">
```

How to fix?

Comment: You're removing items from the Array as you loop through it. So at some point, `shapes[i]` is undefined. Replace `i < 5` with `i < shapes.length` so that it gets updated on each iteration, and do `i--;` after your `splice` (because all the elements after `i` go one step to the left, so you want to stay on the same `i` for the next round)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the game shapes is empty but you are getting `shapes[i]`. That would return `undefined`. And that's what the error means `undefined` doesn't have a property theRow.

You should maybe rerun `main()` or only rerun this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++) {

      for (var j = 0; j < fieldArray[i].length; j++) {

        if (fieldArray[i][j] == 1) {
          shapes.push({
            x: j * 60 + 30,
            y: i * 60 + 30,
            r: 30,
            theRow: i,
            theCol: j,
            fill: "#444444",
            isDragging: false
          });
      }
   }
}
```